# AWS config causes permission error

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

i have a batch file (in windows 10) that backup a file to amazon S3 like so:

```
aws configure set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID <my access key ID here>
aws configure set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY <my secret access key here>
aws configure set default.region eu-west-1

"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\aws.exe" s3api put-object --key c:\myfile.rar --bucket <my bucket name here> --body c:\myfile.rar
```

when i run this batch file from command line it gives those errors:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\myname/.aws/config'

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\myname/.aws/config'

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\myname/.aws/config'
{
"VersionId": "68BYVDOtEdTn8rsygmisYgjddcPbZN67",
"ETag": "\"0c158cd9e8c7f60615a2e1752de479be\""
}
```

but the file DOES get uploaded to s3 probably because the correct AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are already there in the 'C:\Users\myname/.aws/config' file

when i run "aws configure set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID " in the command line the same error happens.

i tried to change permission of the "C:\Users\myname/.aws/config" file to allow everyone all permissions but still the same error happens. also tried to install the latest AWSCLI ,nothing changed.

my real problem is that when this batch file runs from windows scheduler it never finish execution and no file is uploaded to s3. this batch file was working 4 day ago and i didn't change anything

any help apperciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was able to resolve the problem by using :

```
SET AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<my key id>
SET AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<my key>
SET AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
```